# Hot to block access to page with defined URL in ASP.NET site on IIS except from one defined IP?

Tags: windows, security, iis, networking, webserver

We have ASP.NET web site hosted on IIS.
We need to block access to page "http://www.example.com/sample/page1.aspx" from any IP.
We want to define single IP which can access this page.

What option of IIS or Windows can help me?

Comment: Keep in mind that IP spoofing can circumvent this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing - don't forget to apply robust authentication and authorisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using IIS7 + you could use the URL Rewrite Module http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

However if you are using IIS6 you can try a tool like Helicon ISAPI Rewrite http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/ which will allow you to write an IP based rule.

Comment: URL Rewrite Module does all I need and more

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code behind (although this is not IIS or Windows as you request):

```
if (Request.UserHostAddress == "1.1.1.1") {  }
```

Obviously substitute the IP address you want!

Comment: I can not change source code of site. Can I write ASP.NET Module with such functionality?